# Visual Studio 2022 and C#.NET project problems with MySQL version

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2022

I have a C#.NET project in Visual Studio 2022 that was created over an earlier version of MySQL.  I have upgraded MySQL and consequently had to update the MySQL `.dll`.  Now I am getting the below `CS1705` error when compiling the program.

I can't figure out where the project points to `System.Runtime Version=4.1.2.0` and how to change it to use `System.Runtime Version=6.0.0.0`. If I create a new project, I do not have this problem so it is something stuck in the old project.

I have been googling this for a while and have found a lot of answers but the steps they suggest are not doable (options missing, lines missing from config files, etc.)

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

> Error  CS1705  Assembly 'MySql.Data' with identity 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Comment: Are you using NuGet and `<PackageReference>` or are you manually maintaining a bunch of `.dll` files with manual references?

Comment: Did you check target frameworks on Project settings?

Comment: I'm not sure how NuGet would know which version of MySQL.dll I need in my project. The version on my machine is the version that is required for the version of MySQL database that I have installed.  It is the only .dll that I had to add to my project so no, I am not maintaining a bunch of .dll files.

Comment: When I look at the project, I can only select a framework up to 4.8.  There is an option to "Install other frameworks" but that takes me to a webpage to install stuff on my laptop.  I don't see why this would be necessary because new projects allow up to 6.0.  Also, that screen looks totally different between the two projects.

Comment: You need to select the `.NET Core Target Framework`.  The 6.0 versions are .NET Core -- the .NET Framework doesn't exist any more.

Comment: So how do I do that with an existing project?  .NET Core is not an option in my dropdown list.  However, it is an option in my new projects.